# Declaring variables in Excel Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to declare variables in Excel cells and use them as parameters for formulas in other cells?

For example I would declare `var1=10` in one of the cells.
In another cell I would use `var1` for calculation like: `=var1*20`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can name cells. This is done by clicking the Name Box (that thing next to the formula bar which says "A1" for example) and typing a name, such as, "myvar". Now you can use that name instead of the cell reference:

```
= myvar*25
```

Comment: For reference, you can also name groups of cells.  Using their values is a bit trickier, but it can be done :)

Comment: @AKX: That was a nice trick! Thanks... 
@Damovisa: Thanks for the additional tip!
Also is there a way of displaying the Cell name we assign in another cell. I would like to display the cell name in the adjacent cell so that the user is able to identify the cell name without clicking it.

Comment: Note:- This is particulary useful when copying formulas. Excel is very "helpful" and adjusts any cell references in the formula. Quite often you want the references to reamin fixed - refering to a nemed cell does the trick.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the names 'r', 'c', 'R', 'C', 'R1', 'C1', etc. because they conflict with built-in row and cell references.

Comment: You can also name formula.  This will reference all populated cells in column A on Sheet1:`=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`.  Create a Data Validation List cell using the name and you'll get a drop-down box listing everything which also extends as you add to the list, or use it in another formula `=SUM(MyList)`.  Such a useful feature.

Answer (score 48):

I also just found out how to do this with the Excel Name Manager (Formulas > Defined Names Section > Name Manager).

You can define a variable that doesn't have to "live" within a cell and then you can use it in formulas.

[image: Excel Name Manager]

Answer (score 6):

The lingo in excel is different, you don't "declare variables", you "name" cells or arrays.

A good overview of how you do that is below: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010342417.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use (hidden) cells as variables. E.g., you could hide Column C, set C1 to

```
=20
```

and use it as

```
=c1*20
```

Alternatively you can write VBA Macros which set and read a global variable.

**Edit:** [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733019/declcaring-variables-in-excel-cells/733044#733044) renders my Answer partially incorrect. I had no idea you could name cells in Excel.

Comment: Did that @HopefullyHelpful