# Use Excel/OpenOffice cell names within drag-completition

Tags: variables, cell, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a lot of measured values in each column. I use formulas under those values to calculate with them. I always edit the first column and drag-complete (small square in the south-east of the selected cell) to change the other columns, too.

It was fine while dealing with 5 values, but with 20 values in a formula, things are getting complicated. I would like to use cell names, as I found in [Variable in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733019/declaring-variables-in-excel-cells), but when I use drag-complete, this cells are not adapted for the next column, like $D$1 does instead of D1.

Ideas for solutions:

1. Perhaps I can declare an row of cells as an array and index it with cellname(row), but how is this possible?
2. Perhaps it is easier with a small vba script, but I would like to avoid this.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

I was afraid that my question is not that clear. I will try to clearify it with the following files. Thus the Excel-Tag is removed, I uploaded an ods-File:

My file looks like the uploaded short example [example.ods](http://www.lukas-drude.de/wp-content/uploads/example.ods).

I created cell names in the second column like "`size`". Then I have put a human readable formula like "`=size+step+thickness*weight`" in `C7`. When I drag-complete it to cells `D7` and `E7` like shown in [example.png](http://www.lukas-drude.de/wp-content/uploads/example.png). I get of course the same result as in `C7`, because the cell names are used as absolute names like `$B$2` for example.

How can I have human readable formulas applied to `D7` and `E7` without editing `D7` and `E7` by hand? When I use for C7 "`=C2+C3+C4*C5`", I can use the drag-completition of course.

I hope this is more clear now. I guess this is some basic functionality, but I just don't know how to describe it well. Perhaps you have a similar idea to have it more readable than "`=C2+C3+C4*C5`".

Comment: Is it safe to say that the Excel tag doesn't belong since it's an openoffice-calc problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in OpenOffice.org Calc as well as in LibreOffice Calc, but it's crucial to define the cell names for every column that will be evaluated by the formula. Here's a step-for-step solution, based on the example document:

1. Start with a spreadsheet containing just the values together with row and column heads:
   [image: Ranges 1]
2. Create the cell range names:

   a. Select the data range **including the column holding the row names** (OOo will use those Strings as names in the next steps):

   [image: Named Ranges 2]

   b. Select "`Insert -> Names... -> Create`":

   [image: Create names...]

   c. Select "Left Column" to name the rows based on the content of the first column:

   [image: ... with names based on left column]

   Result: four names, one for each row, named as desired:

   [image: resulting names]
3. Create the formula for the first data row (here incomplete, demonstrating OOo's tooltips):
   [image: formula]
4. Drag-complete for all other data rows, giving the final result (with `Tools -> Detective -> Trace precedents` activated - the detective points to the array's first column, but the formula will use the values of the current column):

   [image: final result]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. As I see, there is a build in functionality but I was just not able to discribe it well. => +1

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. (I wish I could upvote this more!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative references in Names, it easier to use R1C1 mode for this:

Define a Name Size with a RefersTo of =R2C
Then wherever you use the name Size in a formula it will refer to the current column and row 2

Comment: I do not understand this answer. But the other answer solved the problem. Thank you anyway.