# Excel: weird IF-statement "IF(case=2;x;y)"

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to reverse-engineer a somewhat complex Excel file and cannot seem to get past this weird statement:

```
=+IF(case=2;$AE$43;AG43)
```

There are two things that I don't understand:

1. The logical test. What does the "case" refer to in this context? I tried searching the file and web for answer, but couldn't find one. The workbook does not include any macros.
2. The true-value. The formula is located in the cell AE43, so how can it refer to itself?

Comment: About "case": maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733019/declaring-variables-in-excel-cells

Comment: @saina: please *remove* "Thanks" instead of *adding* ".. in advance"! See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262087/trailing-thanks-in-questions

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `case` is a named-range. You can view these on the *Formula* ribbon through the *Name Manager*. They can refer to cells, ranges, constants, formulas.

And regarding to the circular (self) referencing - you can set Excel to allow these by doing **Iterative calculation** - see more here [Remove or allow a circular reference](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-0b969f34-d1d9-427a-926b-6e1b64e1ac0b)...

Looks like there will be a bit of investigation down those paths - so good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim ReverseEngineer As Double
Dim Constant As String

ReverseEngineer = Range("AE43")

Select Case ReverseEngineer
Case Is >= 90
Constant = "Newton"
Case Is >= 80
Constant = "Einstein"
Case Is >= 70
Constant = "Galileo"
End Select
```