# Parsing variable names from cell content

Tags: excel

I learned [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733019/declaring-variables-in-excel-cells) that I can declare variables in Excel by naming cells. Now I'm wondering whether it'd be possible to parse text in a cell to call this variable.
Say I name cell A1 "var1", and assign it the value `0.5`, and cell A2 "var2" with the value `0.75`. Then I want to do the following:

```
     B    C    D
1    var1 10   =B1*C1
2    var2 10   =B2*C2
3    var2 10   =B3*C3
4    var2 10   =parse(B4)*C4
5    var1 10   =CELL(B5)*C5
6    var1 10   =VALUE(B6)*C6
```

that is, multiply the values in column `D` by either `var1` or `var2`, which is read from the same row in column `C`. Rows 4, 5, and 6 show some unsuccessful attempts of what I have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `INDIRECT` function. In cell `D6` the formula you want is `=INDIRECT(B6)*C6`.

Note that in Excel 2010 or later, you can't use `var1` as a cell name, because it looks like a cell reference. You would have to use something like `_var1` or `variable1` instead.

Comment: Great, thank you! And thanks for the hint about `var1` as well, while I was only using this as an example here and not in my actual application, it's still good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INDIRECT()` command to query both a range and a named range.
Try `=INDIRECT("myVar1")*C6`